# Visual Studio 2013 theme with light background

Tags: visual-studio

Does Visual Studio 2013 have a built-in way to set an overall theme with dark text on a light background?

Comment: The "Light" theme uses a white background and darker text, though it's not clear how dark of text you want.

Comment: Tools >> Options, "General", choose "Light" from the drop-down for "Color Theme".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the very first thing shown by selecting the Tools, Options menu item. Select the Light theme and you get dark text on a light background.